# Hardware for Generating Low Frequency Vibrations

Tags: frequency, hardware, vibration, vibration-motor

I am interested in having a small device generate low frequency vibrations in the range of 1Hz - 10Hz which can be adjustable. Doing my research, I came across small coin shaped motors which are ideal in size, but have a high RPM 12000-15000 which would translate to a high frequency. Are there any devices that can generate low frequency vibrations? I am open to motors or other hardware that can easily be purchased.

Comment: "This is not a shopping site" - but there are cell phone vibration micro-motors that you can buy off-the-shelf.

Comment: A loudspeaker driven by a suitable source could generate low level vibrations at those frequencies. The bigger the loudspeaker the better of course.

Comment: @Barry I’m assuming that the speaker can do this without sound?

Comment: You won't get much power from a speaker at infrasound frequencies

Comment: think of the motion of your knee when you ride a bicycle

Comment: You can fit an unbalanced weight on any motor (provided it is securely mounted!).  A lathe with a substantial workpiece offset on the faceplate will do the job scarily well. For your use case, a geared motor you can drive at 60 to 600rpm might be more practical.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called an [audio exciter](https://www.parts-express.com/resources-buyers-guide-exciters) or a 'bass shaker'.

It's basically the magnet and voice coil of a loudspeaker without the cone and frame. In their intended use of turning walls, doors, ceiling tiles etc into loudspeakers, you connect the armature to a panel, and the mass of the stator is usually sufficient, at audio frequencies, to get reasonable efficiency when shaking the panel.

But they also work right down to 10 Hz, 1 Hz, DC even. The problem at these frequencies is providing a heavy enough stator. The vibration power will divide between the stator and armature in the ratio of their effective masses. If the stator is too light, you'll be shaking the stator more than the load. Choose a type where you can add mass to the body of the exciter, or be able to mount it on something massive.